# Proving consistent/inconsistency of a fusion of KF estimates

Tags: naive-bayes, kalman-filter, consistency

I have a distributed fusion scenario with a single target where two sensor nodes $i,j$ estimate the true state $\mathbf{x}$ using a local Kalman filter. The (linear, Gaussian) measurement errors of both the nodes can be assumed to be indpendent.

The local estimates $(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{P}_i)$, $(\mathbf{x}_j, \mathbf{P}_j)$ (which now have correlated estimation errors) are fused together using a Kalman filter, generating the fused estimate,

\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}_f = ( \mathbf{P}^{-1}_i + \mathbf{P}^{-1}_j )^{-1}\\
\mathbf{x}_f = \mathbf{P}_f (\mathbf{P}^{-1}_i\mathbf{x}_i + \mathbf{P}^{-1}_j\mathbf{x}_j)
\end{align}

The fused estimate using a standard KF in this case is proven to be inconsistent since it ignores the cross-correlation between the two estimates.

*I'm looking for a theoretical proof that the estimate is inconsistent*. Practically, I can setup a Monte-Carlo simulation to calculate the normalized estimation error squared (NEES) and show that the average NEES is not $\chi^2$ distributed with $n$ degrees of freedom (within the confidence regions).

This will help in proving that estimators with the following structures are consistent,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}_f = ( \mathbf{P}^{-1}_i + \mathbf{P}^{-1}_j - \Gamma^{-1} )^{-1}\\
\mathbf{x}_f = \mathbf{P}_f (\mathbf{P}^{-1}_i\mathbf{x}_i + \mathbf{P}^{-1}_j\mathbf{x}_j - \Gamma^{-1}\gamma)
\end{align}

with some bounds on $(\Gamma, \gamma)$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of consistency with reference to posterior estimates in a Kalman filter is that the updated variance-covariance matrix $P$ should match the expected mean-square error. Thus

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[(x-\hat{x})(x-\hat{x})^T \right] = P, \quad \text{for consistency} 
\end{align}

The estimation error for naive fusion of cross-correlation estimates, $\tilde{x}_\text{n}$, and corresponding covariance are,

\begin{align}
\tilde{x}_\text{n} = P_n^f\left(P_i^{-1}\tilde{x}_i + P_j^{-1}\tilde{x}_j\right); \quad P_n^f = \left( P_i^{-1} + P_j^{-1}\right)^{-1}
\end{align}
where $\tilde{x}_i$ is the estimation error in $i^\text{th}$ estimate.

Evaluating consistency,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(\tilde{x}_\text{n}\tilde{x}^T_\text{n} \right) - P^f_n = 0,
\end{align}
should hold.

Substituting the terms, we get,
\begin{align}
P_n^f\left[P_i^{-1} + P_j^{-1} + P_i^{-1}P_{ij}P_j^{-1} + P_j^{-1}P_{ji}P_i^{-1} \right]\left(P_n^f\right) - P^f_n = 0
\end{align}

where $P_{ij} = P_{ji}^T$ are the cross-correlation matrices. Note that transpose of matrices has not been used, owing to symmetricity. Multiplying both sides by $\left(P_n^f\right)^{-1}$, and canceling like terms, we are left with :

\begin{align}
P_i^{-1}P_{ij}P_j^{-1} + P_j^{-1}P_{ji}P_i^{-1} = 0
\end{align}

Therefore the naive fusion is consistent only when the matrice $P_{ij}$ and $P_{ji}$ are 0, implicitly implying the estimates have to be independent.